# Cannot change background-color of tr element in Chrome DevTools Styles panel

Tags: css, html-table, google-chrome-devtools

I have the following HTML:

```
...
<tr role="row" class="odd">
  <td width="70" ...
  <td class=" customHoverEnabled" ...
  <td ...
  <td class="text-right" ...
  <td class="last-child text-right" ...
</tr>
...
```

I have not been able to change the `background-color` attribute of the `tr` tag using the Styles panel in Chrome (canary) DevTools, like so:

[image]

What befuddles me is this: Doesn't `element.style` have the final say in what style is applied to an element?  Shouldn't it be able to override anything applied earlier?

When I style `element.style` for the inner `td` elements, it works, and the background color changes.

How can I go about understanding this problem? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do your `td` elements have a background-color defined? Because the `tr` wraps around these, if they do you wouldn't necessarily see the `tr` background. Try setting the style on `td` elements to `background-color: transparent;` If that's not it could you provide a code snippet example?

Comment: THANK YOU! That was it.  Unfortunately, I can only upvote you once!

Answer (score 1):

I can see you're using Bootstrap, Bootstrap comes with styles for tables out of the box from memory. And no, element.style doesn't have the final say, I'd say you were correct if you were talking about JavaScript (element.style.display for example).